# CodeIgniter without a Database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Sorry if this is a simple question, is it possible to load codeigniter without a db setup?

I have sess_use_db set to false in the config, I tried renaming database.php to something else but it still wants to load it, I turned active records off also.

I tried commenting everything out in the database.php and it said no database settings found, autoload doesn't load the db.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Since it can run with a variety of different RDBMS, the answer is: yes, it can run without a MySQL server available. The question is probably, how to configure it to run without any db server at all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Theoretically, there should be no reason that CI needs a database. sess_use_db=false just stops CI from storing it's session information in a database. Check that you are not autoloading the database files in config/autoload.php

You could set the database type to 'sqlite' in config/database.php if you simply want to avoid setting up mysql, but you will need to have sqlite installed.

HTH

Comment: I actually had a controller loading the database instead of autoload, so i commented it out and its working without mysql! thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 13):

You just need to remove or comment the following line from autoload.php file in config folder:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you should check your `$autoload['libraries']` and remove database.

Answer (score 5):

By default, CodeIgniter does not use the database at all.

Answer (score 4):

Remove or comment `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');`

in autoload.php. This will enable Code Igniter to load without using database

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the much older existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60183502/209139.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `database` from `config/autoload.php`

Current:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

Then remove database:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought so. I don't see why you then wouldn't be able to hard-code data within your models.

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old thread but answers for a clearer answer.

You need to check in two places `config.php` and `autoload.php` as the website depends on two things which depend on database, which are autoload 'database'  & 'sessions' which we need to remove.

But for `sessions`, rather than eliminating it from autoload, we can keep it by just changing its configuration setting.

In **Config.php** : you need to modify 'session' settings by changing its driver to:

`$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';` .

In **autoload.php** :  you need to modify the 'library' by removing "database" :

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'form_validation');`

Also, do make sure that your site doesn't have any funtions calling for database.

That should fix your issues.